# Wrapper for Serializing an Object in Java JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I want to persist an `Object` in Java. After some research, i found that this can be done using a wrapper class.

Here's what i came up with:

```
public class ObjectWrapper implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -343767114791490410L;
    private ObjectWrapper object;

  public ObjectWrapper(Object object) {

        this.object = (ObjectWrapper) object;
        try {
            serialize(object);
        } catch (NotSerializableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }

  private byte[] serialize(Object object) throws NotSerializableException {

    try {
        // Serialize data object to a file
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("object.ser"));
        out.writeObject(object);
        out.close();

        // Serialize data object to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(object);
        out.close();

        // Get the bytes of the serialized object
        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();

        return buf;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new NotSerializableException("Error serializing the object!");
    }
  }

  public ObjectWrapper getObject() throws NotSerializableException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("object.ser");
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        ObjectWrapper x = new ObjectWrapper(object);
        x = (ObjectWrapper) reader.readObject();
        reader.close();
        return x;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new NotSerializableException("Error serializing the object!");
    }

  }

}
```

Since i'm learning JPA, my question is: is this a correct approach to this problem ? Can this wrapper class be simplified ? I find it a bit odd to first serialize the object to a file. Is this really necessary ?

Comment: You are not using JPA in your code, what relationship is there with JPA? Are you trying to persist your object in a database? If so, this is most likely not the correct approach, but you should probably read more documentation about JPA first.

Comment: @DidierL yes i'm trying to persist the object in a database. I need to have the type `Object`, because i'm going to store `Strings`, `Integer` and a `List`, so i was trying to encapsulate it in a wrapper class, serialize it, and then persist it.

Comment: JPA implementations already know how to serialize an object, and besides you should just make your object Serializable

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't _really_ want to serialize an object to database. Your serialized object data cannot be used (easily) outside your java application. Serialized objects are difficult to maintain on the long run. Usually, you will prefer to implement a mapping between the object's fields and the database (i.e. ORM), and that's where JPA comes into place. See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191269/java-serialization-advantages-and-disadvantages-use-or-avoid

Answer (score 3):

JPA it's abstraction above different ORMs. So, a main target of it is object-relational mapping. In your case you just save object as byte array without mapping on any relational model (in database meaning).
In general serialization and JPA/ORM it's different tasks with different aims.
If you want to persist object as is in relational database you may save it as BLOB in one column in some table.

```
@Entity
public class ObjectWrapper {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long objectId;

    @Lob
    private Serializable object;

    public Long getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(Long objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public Serializable getObject() {
        return object;
    }

    public void setObject(Serializable object) {
        this.object = object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you show me how to do that with a simple example ?

Comment: As you can find out in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11735570/980776, you can just declare filed of Serialized object and it will be automatically serialized into @Lob. I also added small example in my answer. Of course you should also configure JPA environment for test it.

Comment: That's great, but weren't you supposed to do the actual serialize of the object ? As you said in your answer to save it as a BLOB

Comment: Of course, but object have to implement Serializable interface as market which means that object may be serialized.

Comment: Yes, but my question is how can i do the actual serialize of the object ? I'm trying to solve this error type : `The type [...] for the attribute [...] on the entity class [...] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.`

Comment: It means that some of object fields are not serializable. You should check it.

Comment: Yes, and that's the whole point of writing a wrapper class, so i can serialize those objects of type `Object`. I just don't know how do it properly, since what i've done is not correct.