# Spring Boot Entity model member converter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here my problem, I have to store serialized website's cookie information in DB, and I tried to write a simple PesistentConverter to it can be convert Map to String and vice-versa. But the IDE show a warning about this:

```
'Basic' attribute type should not be a map
```

Here my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "website")
public class Website implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "name", length = 16, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "serialized_cookie_map", nullable = false, length = 2048)
    @Convert(converter = CookieMapPersistenceConverter.class)
    @NotNull
    private Map<String,String> serializedCookieMap;
    
    ...
}
```

CookieMapPersistenceConverter:

```
public class CookieMapPersistenceConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> stringStringMap) {
        return stringStringMap.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
        MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, String.class);
        HashMap<String,String> convertedMap = null;
        try {
            convertedMap = mapper.readValue(s, mapType);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertedMap;

    }
}
```

I'm using the 2.6.3 version of Spring Boot.

Many thanks your time!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Basics):

> Any attributes that have no other annotations and do not reference
> other entities will be automatically mapped as basic.

and according to the table from the above link map is not a basic type. so IDE is right about

```
'Basic' attribute type should not be a map
```

I suggest try the following approach to see it satisfies your requirements or not.

```
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", length = 16, nullable = false)
  @NotNull
  private String id;

  @ElementCollection
  @MapKeyColumn(name="property")
  @Column(name="value")
  @CollectionTable(name="cookies", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
  @NotNull
  private Map<String,String> serializedCookieMap;
  //setter and getter
```

and the code for repositry:

```
@Repository
public interface WebsiteRepository extends CrudRepository<Website, String> {}
```

code I did for test:

```
Website w = new Website();
w.setId("id");
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("key1", "value1");
m.put("key2", "value2");
m.put("key3", "value3");
w.setSerializedCookieMap(m);
repo.save(w);
```

which creates two table named `WEBSITE` and `COOKIES` and the content of each is like this:

```
WEBSITES:
ID  
id
```

and:

```
COOKIES:
ID      VALUE   PROPERTY  
id  value1  key1
id  value2  key2
id  value3  key3
```

if you insist to store Serialized version of map take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931736/wrapper-for-serializing-an-object-in-java-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried same thing in my project (with same version of spring boot). I did not notice any warning.

But here are some suggestions...

1. The field you have annotated `@convert` not meant to be persisted in DB. So instead of `@column` try using `@Transient`.
2. You can also try using `@Type( type = "json" )` instead of `@convert`.
3. Also this can be possibly issue with IDE, so just to ignore it as a
   warning you can use `@SuppressWarnings("JpaAttributeTypeInspection")` annotation.